# Thread information for a process

Tags: windows, multithreading, monitoring

I want to use to tool which can tell me details(more than threadID) of all the running threads in a windows application. Please suggest me some. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first one came to my mind is *Process Explorer*:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: Specific to each thread in a process, ProcessExplorer tells you about start time and address, context switches, kernel and user time, priorities, gives a stack trace. It lets you see and change permissions, suspend and kill threads. Plus, it tells you about 50 or so metrics about the surrounding process, of which a dozen can be graphed, too. What else would one need specific to a thread?